# Warning: Declaration of QuietSkin::feedback error

Tags: errors

Good day . So today i've updated my wordpress version to 5.3 and after that i started to see this error at the top of all my pages .

> Warning: Declaration of QuietSkin::feedback($string) should be compatible with WP_Upgrader_Skin::feedback($string, ...$args) in /home/.../domains/.../public_html/wp-content/plugins/ocean-extra/includes/wizard/classes/QuietSkin.php on line 12

Does anyone know what this is ? If you do please provide some assistance :) Thank you

Comment: This is not an error, just a "warning", so the website should still be usable. You can disable outputting the warning to your visitors and should contact the authors of the plugin "ocean-extra" - best with the complete warning message - and kindly ask them to fix it.

Comment: Yes, the website is usable but it shows this warning in all my pages . Okey i will try to contact plugin author and tell him about the problem . Hope this works . Thank you

Comment: As for disabling the output, [there are many resources that explain this](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=wordpress+dont+show+php+warning).

Answer (score 1):

If anyone encounters this warning and cannot hide it with changing the line in wp-config.php from true to false , replace `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` or `define('WP_DEBUG', true);`
with this :

```
ini_set('display_errors','Off');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL );
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

It helped me, so I hope it will help you also ;)

Comment: Thanks, man it worked for me...

Answer (score 1):

If you’re using oceanwp theme its probable that you are getting this error after the recent update of WordPress. I am using the oceanwp theme and got the same error just after updating my WordPress and i somehow fixed it. Now i want to share the same with you guy’s so that you can fix your website.

So first login to your hosting account. Yes you will need to fix it from your hosting account. Then go to file manager under your hosting account. Once you are inside file manager just follow this path.

```
public_html/wp-content/plugins/ocean-extra/includes/wizard/classes/QuietSkin.php
```

And then double click on quietskin.php it will download so that you can edit it.

Now open it with notepad++ or any other editor.

Scroll down to bottom and you will see a code like this

```
public function feedback($string) { /* no output */ }
```

Just change it to this :

```
public function feedback($string, …$args) { /* no output */ }
```

And save the file.

Now go back to your browser and reload